# Heron's formula in C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to programming and am running into a problem when trying to create a program which uses Heron's formula to calculate 5 approximations of the square root of a number *i* <= 10.

The formula is:

> *X<sub>n</sub>* + 1 = (*X<sub>n</sub>* + (*i* / *X<sub>n</sub>*)) / 2

I came up with the following code, but it's not working, as the output is nothing.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int zahl = 1, j;
        double root = (zahl / 2);
        while (zahl <= 10);
        {
            j = 0;
            while (j++ < 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,5}", root = (root + (zahl / root)) / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate help or hints related to this issue.

Comment: Does this program even terminate? You initialize `zahl` to 1 (which is not the best name by the way - what number is `number`?) but I never see that you change it anywhere so `while(zahl <= 10)` will always be true and continue looping.

Comment: Do you have a link describing Heron's formula further, for additional context? _I always thought it was related to finding the area of a triangle._

Comment: Did you try to debug your application?

Comment: Suggested reading:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semicolon after your `while` statement, causing the entire apparent body to be ignored:

```
    while (zahl <= 10);    // <-- REMOVE THIS SEMICOLON
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j++ < 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,5}", root = (root + (zahl / root)) / 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @maccettura I did indeed, fixed. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning `while` loops into `for` ones:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
   // for each number in [0..10] range
   for (double number = 1.0; number <= 10.0; ++number) {
     double root = number / 2.0; // <- initial (zeroth) root aproximation

     // we want to calculate 5 approximations:
     for (int app = 1; app <= 5; ++app) {
       root = (root + number / root) / 2.0;

       // string interpolation $"..{some value} .." can be very handy 
       Console.WriteLine($"sqrt({number}) == {root} (app #{i})");
     } 

     // Let's split output 
     Console.WriteLine(); 
   }
 }
```

Be careful with

1. Conditions: `while (zahl <= 10) {...}` should change `zahl` within `{...}` in order to prevent *infinite loop*
2. Semicolons: `while (zahl <= 10);` means "do nothing while zahl <= 10" which results in *infinite loop*

Outcome:

```
sqrt(1) == 1.25 (approximation #1)
sqrt(1) == 1.025 (approximation #2)
sqrt(1) == 1.00030487804878 (approximation #3)
sqrt(1) == 1.00000004646115 (approximation #4)
sqrt(1) == 1 (approximation #5)

sqrt(2) == 1.5 (approximation #1)
sqrt(2) == 1.41666666666667 (approximation #2)
sqrt(2) == 1.41421568627451 (approximation #3)
sqrt(2) == 1.41421356237469 (approximation #4)
sqrt(2) == 1.41421356237309 (approximation #5)

sqrt(3) == 1.75 (approximation #1)
sqrt(3) == 1.73214285714286 (approximation #2)
sqrt(3) == 1.73205081001473 (approximation #3)
sqrt(3) == 1.73205080756888 (approximation #4)
sqrt(3) == 1.73205080756888 (approximation #5)

....

sqrt(9) == 3.25 (approximation #1)
sqrt(9) == 3.00961538461538 (approximation #2)
sqrt(9) == 3.00001536003932 (approximation #3)
sqrt(9) == 3.00000000003932 (approximation #4)
sqrt(9) == 3 (approximation #5)

sqrt(10) == 3.5 (approximation #1)
sqrt(10) == 3.17857142857143 (approximation #2)
sqrt(10) == 3.16231942215088 (approximation #3)
sqrt(10) == 3.16227766044414 (approximation #4)
sqrt(10) == 3.16227766016838 (approximation #5)
```